# Python: Execute new process with elevated privileges

Tags: python, admin, privileges

I have an application which needs admin privileges to run correctly. I need to run this application from a python script.

If I run my command with the following code: `subprocess.Popen(cmdCommand, stderr = outputFile, stdout = outputFile)`,
I receive the exact same errors like the application would return if it isn't run with Admin privileges (I see the errors in the outputFile)

In addition,

- `cmdCommand` has the following format: `RunApplication.cmd param1
  param2`
- I run the python script from cmd.exe which is opened with
  Admin privileges
- the user which I am logged on is Admin on the machine

Sorry for my english :D :D :D

Comment: What operating system. If you're on windows use the `runas` command.

Comment: I'm running on win8. If I use `runas` then I need to give the password everytime? How can I do it to be as automatic as posible?